# Що означає слово "чев’ядіти"?

Tags: значення-слів, дієслова

У вірші Емми Андієвської "Перехресні лінії" натрапила на такі рядки:

> Усесвіт парасолькою бідаки
>
> **Чев'ядіє**, притулений до муру.

Цікавить значення виділеного мною слова, оскільки у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/chev.jadity) його не знайшла.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Словник за ред. Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8) дає значення:

> Чев’ядіти, дію, єш, гл. Хирѣть, болѣть. Це кошеня чогось усе чев’ядіє. Борз. у.

Отже *"чев'ядіти"* означає *хворіти*, *марніти*, *недугувати*.
Ще підтвердження: ["Вибрані праці в п'яти томах"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=r4MKAAAAMAAJ&q=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8&dq=%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLsOuu8-DcAhXENJoKHbX-B0EQ6AEIQzAE). Також зазначу, що [*"чав'ядіти"*](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=r4MKAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%22&dq=%22%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%22&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5q83-8-DcAhUwS5oKHXAXAkIQ6AEIKTAA), - те саме, що й *"чев'ядіти"*

Надалі раджу користуватися більш ніж одним словником, особливо, коли справа стосується застарілих та/або говіркових слів.

Comment: А мені цікаво — що означає «не кошеня»?

Comment: @Sasha, можливо помилка була при оцифровуванні словника, що продублювалася усіма. Може там має бути "Це".

Comment: @muffin, так і є, [на R2U](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=чев'ядіти&dicts=12) цієї помилки нема, мабуть, варто виправити й у цитаті.

Comment: Просто для себе — наразі бачу цей словник у 5 місцях:
[hrinchenko.com](http://hrinchenko.com/),
[KUBG](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/«Словарь_української_мови»),
[R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/s?dicts=12&highlight=on),
[ukrlit.org](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy),
[ULIF](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch).

Comment: @Sasha а на меті ви не додавали посилання всі через циферки 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: @P.Vovk, ні, там лише 2-3 джерела. Треба буде додати. Це я, як пам'ятку для себе, й написав.